# CKEDITOR 5 apply styles in paragraph or p tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I have Inline CKeditor

```
InlineEditor.create(document.querySelector('#editor'), {
    toolbar: {
        items: ['heading', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'link', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'blockQuote', 'insertTable', 'undo', 'redo']
    },
    })
    .then(editor => {
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err.stack);
    });
```

});

And this is my HTML which I have p tag with styles.

```
<div id="editor">
    <p style="color:#000000;"><strong>1. DEFINITIONS</strong></p>

    <p style="margin-left:30px;color:#000000;">
        1.1 PARAGRAPH STYLE NOT WORKING IN CKEDITOR
    </p>
</div>
```

When viewing it in HTML this would be look like

[image]

But when I run it with CKEditor the view look like this and the style is not applied on it

[image]

And this is HTML of CKeditor

[image]

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Are you saving the editor entry data in database. ?

Comment: @ShivendraSingh nope!

Comment: CKEditor 5 will filter out all the content not supported by its features. [Find out why](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/faq.html#why-does-the-editor-filter-out-my-content-styles-classes-elements-where-is-configallowedcontent-true). You'll need to write editor features to allow this kind of content in the editor and/or use existing features. Check out https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/indent.html and https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/font.html#configuring-the-font-color-and-font-background-color-features, they should help you.